# Displaying properties of edges in d3.js network using d3plus.js

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

Is there a way to get the properties of the edges displayed in the tooltip by configuring d3plus network?
I have tried with the example described here with no success http://d3plus.org/workshops/11_29_2013/network/